# Carter Subgroups and Projectors

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups, nilpotence

R. Carter prooved that in finite soluble groups $G$ Carter subgroups $C$ exist and that they are conjugated. Furthermore they are exactly the nilpotent projectors: For every normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ the factor group $CN/N$ is maximal nilpotent in $G/N$.

My question is whether in non-finite soluble groups Carter subgroups (if they exist) are nilpotent projectors.

They are maximal nilpotent also in the infinte case and also for non-solvable groups.

Comment: What is the definition of a Carter subgroup of a general group?

Comment: Its the same: nilpotent and self-normalizing.

Comment: Cross-posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206602/are-carter-subgroups-nilpotent-projectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is answered there, too.

Answer (score 1):

There are different definitions of Carter subgroups in infinite groups. Thus the Carter subgroups of a generalized soluble group are the
locally nilpotent abnormal subgroups (see, for example, Journal of Algebra
Volume 297, Issue 1, 1 March 2006, Pages 273-291, Abnormal subgroups and Carter subgroups in some classes of infinite groups L.A.KurdachenkoaJ.Otal J,A.Russoc, G.Vincenzid.). See also L. A.  Kurdachenko and  I. Ya.  Subbotin.  Abnormal subgroups and Carter subgroups in some infinite groups,  Algebra and Discrete Mathematics,  Number 1.  (2005).  pp.  63 – 77, and 
L.  A.  Kurdachenko,  J.  Otal,  I.  Ya.  Subbotin.  Abnormal,  pronormal,  contranormal,  and Carter subgroups in some generalized minimax groups,  Communications in Algebra,  Volume 33,  Number 12 (2005), 4595 – 4616.